# Google Forms Prefilled URL Limit (Workaround?)

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form that I programmatically pre-fill with data (Using Apps Script). I face the problem that, if the URL is too large, the server responses with HTTP Status 400 (Bad Request). The tested URL has 9.000+ characters
Is there a known workaround this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible GET an infinitely large URL to Google.

A workaround is the following:

- Add a checkbox to the form, with only one possible answer.
- Programmatically prefill the form with all the field, except checkbox above, and `submit()` it.
- Give your user the **Edit Link** using `FormApp.FormResponse.getEditResponseUrl()` [(documentation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl())
- Programmatically ignore / delete items that do not have the checkbox checked.

This works because checkboxes with only one value get automatically filled when the form is opened (and submitted) in a browser, but not before.